# How resolver error of incompatible after install next version 12?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm trying to install nextjs 12 on my machine, however. I get the errors below.

`error execa@7.2.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^14.18.0 || ^16.14.0 || >=18.0.0". Got "16.13.2"`

`error Found incompatible module. info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.`

I used npx create-next-app@12.2.0 for install the nextjs version 12. I expected next to be installed, but I was unsuccessful.

OBS: When i install next 13 i get no error